# how to convert dataframe to panel data format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, panel, reshape

I have dataframe which looks like,

```
                comp           name          base       lstdt   
A122630      삼성자산운용   KODEX 레버리지 코스피 200  2010/02/22   
A123320  미래에셋자산운용   TIGER 레버리지 코스피 200  2010/04/09   
A123320  한국투자신탁운용  KINDEX 레버리지 코스피 200  2012/01/27   
A122630  키움투자자산운용   KOSEF 레버리지 국고채 지수  2012/10/30   
A292340  한국투자신탁운용  KINDEX 일본TOPI      TOPIX  2014/06/16 

           date     code  
A122630  20180102  A122630  
A123320  20180102  A123320  
A123320  20180409  A123320  
A122630  20180409  A122630  
A292340  20180409  A292340  
...
```

How can I convert this kind of data to panel like one,

```
           date     comp
A122630   20180102   삼성자산운용  
A122630   20180409   키움투자자산운용
A123320   20180102   미래에셋자산운용  
A123320   20180409   키움투자자산운용
A292340   20180409   한국투자신탁운용
```

Please help me..
What I tried is this,

```
years = np.tile(np.arange(appended_data.date.min(), appended_data.date.max()+1,1) ,2)
ids = np.repeat(appended_data.code.unique(), appended_data.date.max()-appended_data.date.min()+1)
arrays = [ids.tolist(), years.tolist()]
new_idx = list(zip(*arrays))

dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for item in new_idx:
    for idx in range(len(new_idx)):
        for row in appended_data.iterrows():
            if new_idx[idx][0] == row['code'] and new_idx[idx][1] == row['date']:
                 dataframe['nav'] = row['nav']
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for? A lot of this data seems to have appeared out of thin air.

Comment: It seems your desired (2nd) DataFrame has multiple dates in the date column, but your input DataFrame only has 1 date in the date column. Do you have one DataFrame per date? Have you tried DataFrame.merge()?

Comment: @geonaut, Yes I do have other dates in the dataset, it just that I didn't put them. And I didn't tried merge() yet, Thank you for commenting

Comment: Are the other dates in separate DataFrames, or is all data within a single input DataFrame? Also, what is the first column relate to? I think you might need to expand and check your input and output data examples a little bit.

Comment: @geonaut, in a single dataframe called "appended_data". Also the first column relates to the unique code of specific financial product. it worked as a index

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
df.to_panel()
```

Please note that Panels are descontinued after version 0.23.4. I know this question is old  but still.